# Determine when UIContextMenuInteraction has been dismissed

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

Is there a way to determine when a [UIContextMenuInteraction](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicontextmenuinteraction) has been dismissed?

I’m using UIContextMenuInteraction with a collection view. When the menu is brought up on a cell, I’ll highlight the cell. When it is dismissed, I want to unhighlight the cell.